# Checkmate N Kings with M Knights Perfectly

Tags: optimization, chess, checkerboard

We have this [Existing Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116823/checkmate-n-kings-with-m-knights) which has got the valid and invalid cases listed ; the Accepted Answer is along the lines of what is invalid and what is valid.

But there was a flaw or fault in the Puzzle (not in the Answer, which satisfies the given Conditions) which has been corrected now, by adding a single word.

If you wish to check and see the flaw yourself, you can check the latest change there.

> A king can not move itself out of attack, but it can help some other king come out of attack.

Existing Examples in the earlier Puzzle are all invalid according to this new correction :

> There are N White Kings on the Chess Board.
> There are M Black Knights.
> There is no Black King and no other Piece. Only M+N Squares are occupied.

> Each White King is attacked by at least 1 Black Knight, but it cannot move itself **or some other king** out of attack.

**Maximize N. In the Possible Solutions, Minimize M.**

Needless to mention that the valid Answers there become invalid here:

**Invalid Examples:**

In the Accepted Answer,

> The kings around c7 can take c7 ; then a8 and e8 are not in attack.

[image]

In the Other Answer,

> The kings around b6 can take b6 ; then a8 & c8 are not in attack.

[image]

**Valid Examples:**

[image]

N=3 & M=4

[image]

N=9 & M=12

Comment: Essentially, all kings must be attacked by at least two knights?

Comment: Not necessarily ; There might be no King near a Knight (which can not be taken) ; This Knight can be the only Knight attacking some King(s) , @DanielMathias

Comment: @DanielMathias ... or attacked by a single knight that cannot be captured by any white king.

Comment: Exactly !!! @JaapScherphuis

Comment: So a king can now move into a check by a knight? I don't think that restriction is a flaw in the first puzzle. I think that makes sense.

Comment: That is not the case ; Multiple kings were in check and there is no "valid" move which makes White come out of check in total ; The moves were "transferring" checks around ; @JLee ; Now & before, all the king(s) were already in Check, but (before) which-ever move a king "makes", he could not get out of check but some "moves" could get some other king(s) out of check. While (now) the king(s) can not get out of check and can not even get some other king(s) out of check, even if a "sacrifice" is made  !

Comment: You say "In the accepted answer, The kings around c7 can take c7 ; then a8 and e8 are not in attack." But how can the kings take c7? It is moving into check, and is therefore illegal.

Comment: @Prem I am very confused with the way you worded the puzzle so could you please add images or links to what you mean?

Comment: I got what you are saying & I agree, but (1) Every move leaves the other Kings still in check (2) That being the case, there is no valid move according to "normal Chess", because all moves are invalid (3) In **Earlier Scenario**, a King could move from one check to another check, to help some other King escape the check (4) In **New Scenario**, even that is not Possible, that is, "sacrificing" does not help some other king come out of check (5) It is only a Puzzle !! @JLee

Comment: I will edit it shortly , @VarunW.

Comment: In your example N=9 M=11, c2 can take c3 leaving b1 unattacked.  Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Nice Catch , @FlorianF , I have updated with a fix now !!

Answer (score 6):

I'll stand by my initial comment: All kings should be attacked by at least two knights. If any king is attacked by only one knight, the attacking knight must not be threatened by another king. This greatly reduces the number of kings that can be placed.

Doubling up the knights in loopy walt's answer to the earlier question is a good start, but there is room for improvement.

> This solution has 24 knights attacking 36 kings. The four vacant squares are guarded, providing no safe haven for nearby kings. All knights are guarded, so no king can save himself by capturing a knight. All kings are attacked by at least two knight, so none can be saved by another with the capture of a single knight.
>
>  [image]

Comment: +1 , Currently the Best Answer ! I will wait a while before checking whether somebody else can get a Better Solution !

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE** Saved two knights

> 38 Kings and 24 Knights
>
>  [image]

If I'm not missing something these are

> 38 Kings and 26 Knights
>
>  [image]

Comment: +1 , It looks valid to me !! Currently the Best Answer !!

Answer (score 3):

The answer I got is :

> 24 knights and 36 kings

The position(s):

Position number 1:

> [image]
>  Or if you want to see the lichess version click here https://lichess.org/editor/K1KKKKKK/KKnKnnK1/KnnnnnnK/KnnKKnKK/KKnKKnnK/KnnnnnnK/1KnnKnKK/KKKKKK1K_w_-_-_0_1

Position number 2:

> [image]
>  Or if you want to see the lichess version click here https://lichess.org/editor/KKKKKKKK/K1nnnn1K/KnnnKnnK/KnKKKnnK/KnnKKKnK/KnnKnnnK/K1nnnn1K/KKKKKKKK_w_-_-_0_1

Comment: +1 , It is matching the Other Solution , with a Slight Change !